# Как изменить елемент массива в vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Всем привет)Я новенький в теме vue.js и мне нужна помощь в моём самообучении.
У меня есть страница с формой где я могу создавать таски. Они добавляются в массив, а также этот массив сохраняется в localStorage.
Вопрос в том как мне сделать редактирование выбранного таска.
Сделать так что бы при нажатии на таск он появлялся в отдельном инпуте я сделал, а дальше остановился. Помогите советом ,если есть возможность то и примером, как мне изменить выбранный елемент массива.

```js
const App = {
    data(){
        return{
            editInput:'',
            title:'Notes',
            input:{
                value:'',
                placeholder:'Type ur note'
            },
            notes:['task0','task1','task2']
        }
    },
    watch:{
        notes: {
            handler(updatedList) {
               localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(updatedList));
            },
            deep: true,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getNotes();
    }
    ,
    methods:{
        info(note,index){
            this.editInput = note
        },
        getNotes(){
            const localNotes = localStorage.getItem('notes')
            if(localNotes){
                this.notes = JSON.parse(localNotes);
            }
        },
        onSubmit(){
            this.notes.push(this.input.value)
            this.input.value = ''
        },
        remove(index){

            this.notes.splice(index,1)
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>#9 Notes</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <input type="text" v-model="input.value" :placeholder="input.placeholder" required>
            <button>Add new Note</button>
        </form>
        <div class="notes">
            <div class="note" v-for="(note,index) in notes" :key="index">
                <p><span @click="info(note,index)">&#9998;</span><span @click="remove(index)">&#10005;</span>
                    {{note}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" v-model="editInput">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно редактирование можно сделать вот так. Изменение массивов (точнее что относится к реактивности) описывается в [документации Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#array-change-detection), а работа с самими массивами – в документации JS, [или учебниках](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods).

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      editInput: '',
      title: 'Notes',
      input: {
        value: '',
        placeholder: 'Type ur note'
      },
      notes: ['task0', 'task1', 'task2'],
      editElement: {}, // Создаем переменную (свойство)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    notes: {
      handler(updatedList) {
        localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(updatedList));
      },
      deep: true,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getNotes();
  },
  methods: {
    info(note, index) {
      this.editElement = {
        index,
        value: note
      } // Записываем данные, индекс элемента нам тоже нужно знать
    },
    update() {
      this.notes.splice(this.editElement.index, 1, this.editElement.value) // При сохранении записываем данные
      this.editElement = {} // Очищаем редактируемый элемент
    },
    getNotes() {
      const localNotes = localStorage.getItem('notes')
      if (localNotes) {
        this.notes = JSON.parse(localNotes);
      }
    },
    onSubmit() {
      this.notes.push(this.input.value)
      this.input.value = ''
    },
    remove(index) {

      this.notes.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>#9 Notes</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="app">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <input type="text" v-model="input.value" :placeholder="input.placeholder" required>
        <button>Add new Note</button>
      </form>
      <div class="notes">
        <div class="note" v-for="(note,index) in notes" :key="index">
          <p><span @click="info(note,index)">&#9998;</span><span @click="remove(index)">&#10005;</span> {{note}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Проверяем, что переменная содержит не пустой объект -->
      <template v-if="Object.keys(editElement).length > 0">
        <input type="text" v-model="editElement.value">
        <button @click="update">Save</button>
      </template>

      <!-- Для наглядности -->
      {{ editElement }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```